# How can I install arangodb Client (arangosh etc.) without installing arangodb?

Tags: arangodb

I need to connect to a remote ArangoDB server using a client. I do not see any instructions online to only install the ArangoSH toolkit. How can I install the ArangoSH toolkit without installing the DB itself? Is there any client-only toolkit that I can install?
Thanks,
-Alok

I tried searching for ArangoSH only installation online, but couldn't find any help.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue myself - I have an enterprise instance that I would like to manage using arangosh without installing the database locally.

The only way I've found to do so is to use the arangodb docker container.
Provided you have docker installed, use these terminal commands

```
% docker pull arangodb/arangodb
% docker run --rm -it arangodb/arangodb:latest arangosh --help
```

You will likely require additional environment variable and parameters such as

```
% docker run --rm -it -e ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepassword arangodb/arangodb:latest arangosh --server.endpoint https://myarango.arango.cloud/
```

For a good look at how to use the arango container - refer to
https://hub.docker.com/r/arangodb/arangodb

Answer (score 0):

Clients tools like arangosh, arangodump etc. are available here: https://www.arangodb.com/download-major/

E.g. for MacOS: https://www.arangodb.com/download-major/macos/